# Cant import React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started learning about React and I have problem with importing the library.

*index.html*:

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

*script.js file*:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(<h1> Hello World </h1>, document.getElementById("Root"))
```

Error I get when im opening the index file:

**Cannot GET /ReactDOM%20%5E&%20JSX/index.html**

I imported those 2 scripts from React site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the id on `<div id="root"></div>` is lowercase but in your JS script you're selecting `document.getElementById("Root")` an uppercase id. `document.getElementById` is case sensitive, so your code will probably not render correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to spin up a server running on localhost, that can serve the files. Right now a GET request to your localhost does not work, because there is no server running that hosts the files. You only opened the file with your browser.

Check out [create react app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started) to get started with a good setup.

If you want to manually serve files. Check out the [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) package. You can quickly test this by running

```sh
npx serve folder-name
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping to understand!

Comment: You're welcome. Enjoy stackoverflow - if this answer resolves your question, mark it as solved for others to find it quicker.